# How to add an EventListener on all the dom element that have a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, onclick, addeventlistener

I have some span in my DOM that have the class="foo" and all the spans are created dynamically.

With TypeScript i want to add an onClick Event to all of them after their creation.

I have something like this :

```
var foos = document.body.querySelectorAll(".foo");
foos.forEach(function (item) {            
    item.addEventListener("click", () => { 
        console.log(item); 
    });
});
```

But i can't do forEach on a NodeListOf.

foos = Array.from(foos) does not work because : 'from' doesn't exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made three different approaches that you can use, they are very simple, please open each code snippet to see it working.

1 - This Example shows how to add the listener **AFTER** the creation of elements.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var a = document.createElement('input');
  a.type = 'button';
  a.value = 'click me ' + i;
  a.className = 'foo';
  document.body.append(a);
}

//JQUERY WAY
$('.foo').on('click', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2 - This Example shows how to add the listener **BEFORE** the creation of elements.

```js
//JQUERY WAY
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var a = document.createElement('input');
  a.type = 'button';
  a.value = 'click me ' + i;
  a.className = 'foo';
  document.body.append(a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3 - And finally, if don't want jQuery, here's a **Vanilla JS** example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var a = document.createElement('input');
  a.type = 'button';
  a.value = 'click me ' + i;
  a.className = 'foo';
  document.body.append(a);
}

//VANILLA JS WAY
var myElems = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');
myElems.forEach(function(elem){
  elem.onclick = function(){
    console.log(elem.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! i tried with the two others solutions but it worked only from the console not in my entire code

Answer (score 3):

Use simple `for` loop for this. You can get elements for each index in the `foos` array and assign click event on them. This is because `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which is indexed like an array, but not an Array so you can't call the array methods on it as it is not a real array.

```
var foos = document.body.querySelectorAll(".foo"));
for(var i=0; i<foos.length; i++){
    foos[i].addEventListener("click", () => { 
        console.log(item); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question with `jquery`, here's the `jquery` way:

```
$(".foo").click( function() { 
   // Do something here
});
```